# How to add image to the article?

Tags: python-3.x, pelican, static-site-generation

I realize that it should be something like this: `{filename}path/to/file` or `{attach}path/to/file` but how to specify path in the template `<img src="?"/>` in order to render properly?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `{static}path/to/file`.

Furthermore, you don't have to specify the `img` tag in your templates.

Pelican (or rather docutils) takes care of it.

**Edit:**

With regard to lay-out, I tend to use:

```
.. image:: {static}/path/to/image.jpg
    :width: 100%
```

Comment: Static content which the same for every page I'm linking in the base template this way (<img src="{{ SITEURL }}/theme/images/filename.ext). It works fine. But I'm talking about unique images for every article.

Comment: `{static}` works with images in articles. See elso https://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/content.html#linking-to-static-files.

Comment: It kind of "works". But how to style such image? It break my layout.

Comment: See updated answer. If you are using a custom theme, you will probably have to show the

Comment: This is rst sintax. I'm using Mardown. I've fixed styling by applying styles to the img nested in p tag.